# Editor.CreateEditor causing Garbage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Editor.Create Editor as such to create an object's custom inspector in my custom window.

```
componentEditor = (AudioEventBaseDrawer)Editor.CreateEditor(currentSelectedEvent[0]);
```

Now, no matter what I seem to do to the instance of component editor, it stays in memory through recompilation. The reason it is obvious that it does is that once I delete the asset in project it is related to, be it right now or later after x compilations, it's going to throw :

SerializedObjectNotCreatableException: Object at index 0 is null

Errors that I can't remove unless I restart Unity. In my case it's because there is an AudioSource component on the asset, which I am also creating via Editor.CreateEditor(), and when it is Destroy, the core code still searches for it (AudioSourceInspector.OnEnable).

What I have tried to do is to make sure that I use DestroyImmediate on the Editors that I have created right before I delete the assets, I am also using DestroyImmediate on the AudioSource. I just basicly destroy everything, and it still causes the error.

This is my code, commented (AudioEventBase exists together with an AudioSource on the gameobject) :

```
    private void DeleteEvents(List<AudioEventBase> events)
            {
                AudioManagerEditorUtilities.HandleEventMoveLoadingType(contextData,contextData.Contexts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == currentSelectedContext), null, events);
                foreach (AudioEventBase evnt in events)
                {
                    if (componentEditor != null)
                    {
                        //Here, Dispose calls DestroyImmediate(audioSourceEditor), which is the Editor.CreateEditor of the AudioSource, first
                        componentEditor.Dispose();
                        //We destroy the Editor.CreateEditor of the current AudioEventBase
                        DestroyImmediate(componentEditor);
                    }
     
                    string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(evnt.gameObject);
                    GameObject gameObject = evnt.gameObject;
                    //We destroy the component AudioEventBase
                    DestroyImmediate(evnt, true);
                    foreach (AudioSource source in gameObject.GetComponents<AudioSource>())
                    {
                        //We destroy all possible AudioSources on the GameObject
                        DestroyImmediate(source, true);
                    }
                 
                    //Finally, we destroy the GameObject itself
                    AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset(assetPath);
                }
                AssetDatabase.Refresh();
                //We destroy and recreate the list from all other existing objects that were not deleted
                RefreshAudioEventList();
            }
```

Is there some other cleanup I am missing to avoid this error?